# Avoid instant trigger of multiple click on Touchableopacity in react-native

Tags: react-native

When I click submit button (TouchableOpacity is used) multiple times instantly it will trigger the function multiple times. Any suggetion to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a loading state and pass that state to the disabled prop of touchableOpactiy.That way the button will be disable while the operation completes

Comment: But if we click continuously that method won't work and the onpress action will trigger multiple times.(In some cases with API calling like post comment will post multiple  comments if we continue pressing the button and the internet is a little slow.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `state` and `settimeout` function for that,

after clicking the `TouchableOpacity` just set the state false and in set timeout change it to true after some time

Comment: But if we click continuously  that method won't work and the onpress action  will trigger multiple time